# SQL Count() and GROUP BY

Tags: sql

I have problem with a (simple) SQL query.

The background is, each `Book` has one (or more) defined `BookLanguages`

That query returns 9 books which is OK.

```
SELECT b.BookID
FROM Book b
JOIN BookLanguages bls ON b.BookID = bls.BookID
WHERE b.IsActive= 1 
       AND
        bls.BookLanguageID = 25
GROUP BY b.BookID
```

But, I must have the total books count which meets that criteria (for pagination purpose).

if I just run that query

```
SELECT COUNT(b.BookID)
FROM Book b
JOIN BookLanguages bls ON b.BookID = bls.BookID
WHERE b.IsActive= 1 
       AND
        bls.BookLanguageID = 25
GROUP BY b.BookID
```

I get 9 rows with the 1 value (which is the languages count, because when I remove the `AND bls.BookLanguageID = 25` condition, I get 9 rows with values 1 or 2 - because some books have 2 languages defined)

So, the point is - how the get just the `9`number instead of the 9 rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `DISTINCT` and no `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.BookID)
FROM Book b
JOIN BookLanguages bls ON b.BookID = bls.BookID
WHERE b.IsActive= 1 
       AND
        bls.BookLanguageID = 25
```

GROUPing BY Id returns a row for each value of Id, so 9 rows in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the group by

```
Select
  Count(*)
From
  Book b
    Inner Join
  BookLanguages bls 
    On b.BookID = bls.BookID
Where
  b.IsActive= 1 And
  bls.BookLanguageID = 25
```